# How can I maintain previous state param on 404?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to working with Angular and I need some help with router-ui package.

Several of my states are made up of a dynamic value like so:

```
.state('state-name', {
  url: `${dynamicValue}/state-name`,
  abstract: true,
  template: '<ui-view/>',
  data: {
    layout: {
      footer: false
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    context: resolveContext
  },
});
```

This value is passed via radio buttons that the user selects an option from. This all works fine, but the problem I am having is, if that user enters a wrong URL after choosing a value, it redirects them back to the first radio option rather than maintaining their choice. This is due to conditions I have setup if the user does not choose an option.

E.g.

Available Options:

```
1. 1234
2. 5678
```

If I choose:

```
5678
```

It generates this URL:

```
domain.com/5678/state-name
```

If I trigger a 404:

```
domain.com/5678/state-name/xyxyxyxyxxy
```

It redirects to:

```
domain.com/1234/state-name
```

Rather than:

```
domain.com/5678/state-name/
```

I have tried to modify the `otherwise()` function, but not having much luck. How can I maintain the previously chosen option, which is permanent until they choose a different option? Would it be better to modify the state within the controller `$onInit()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach to resolve this issue.

```
.state('parentState', {
  url: `:id/state-name`,
  abstract: true,
  template: '<ui-view/>',
  data: {
    layout: {
      footer: false
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    context: resolveContext
  },
}).state('childState', {
  url: `:id/state-name/xyxyxy`,
  abstract: true,
  template: '<ui-view/>',
  data: {
    layout: {
      footer: false
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    context: resolveContext
  },
});
```

So, the first option will take 'id' parameter dynamically.

You can call it by passing id parameter to state name in ui-sref. Let say

```
<a ui-sref="childState({'id':5678})"> 
    <input type="radio" value="5678" />
</a>
```

Same way you can create for others or call it using ng-repeat.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This isn't really an issue with how the value is captured. This area is fully working and way past changing.